# The first item is broken when I scroll back

Tags: dart, flutter, runtime-error

I try to make a hacker news reader. I get an error but I am not quite sure what is going on.
When I try to do the following step, the first item is vanishing and get some error log to tell me  '_debugSubtreeRelayoutRootAlreadyMarkedNeedsLayout()': is not true.

1. Scroll up the list.
2. Scroll down the list to the top.

It looks like this

[image: It looks like this]

And I also upload the demo if it is helpful.
https://github.com/keeweeChang/flutter_news/tree/list_error

And here is the git to show the error situation.
https://media.giphy.com/media/XKGJrdAvgLcy9zyJwM/giphy.gif

> ### Error log: I/flutter (30902): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY  ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> I/flutter (30902): The following assertion was thrown building
>   FutureBuilder(state:
>
> I/flutter (30902): _FutureBuilderState#fd3d0):
>
> I/flutter (30902): 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed
>   assertion: line 1409 pos 14:
>
> I/flutter (30902):
>   '_debugSubtreeRelayoutRootAlreadyMarkedNeedsLayout()': is not true.
>
> I/flutter (30902):
>
> I/zygote (30902): Do partial code cache collection, code=59KB,
>   data=43KB
>
> I/flutter (30902): Either the assertion indicates an error in the
>   framework itself, or we should provide substantially
>
> I/flutter (30902): more information in this error message to help you
>   determine and fix the underlying cause.
>
> I/flutter (30902): In either case, please report this assertion by
>   filing a bug on GitHub:
>
> I/flutter (30902):
>   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
>
> I/flutter (30902):
>
> I/flutter (30902): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>
> I/flutter (30902): #2 RenderObject.markNeedsLayout
>   (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1409:14)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #3 RenderBox.markNeedsLayout
>   (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1842:11)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #4 RenderObject.dropChild
>   (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1158:5)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #5
>   _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin.child= (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2744:7)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #6
>   SingleChildRenderObjectElement.removeChildRenderObject
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4909:18)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #7 RenderObjectElement.detachRenderObject
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4749:36)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #8 Element.detachRenderObject.
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2866:13)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #9 ComponentElement.visitChildren
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3775:14)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #10 Element.detachRenderObject
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2865:5)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #11 Element.deactivateChild
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2995:11)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #12 Element.updateChild
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2760:7)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #13 ComponentElement.performRebuild
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3752:16)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #14 Element.rebuild
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3564:5)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #15 BuildOwner.buildScope
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2277:33)
>
> I/zygote (30902): After code cache collection, code=59KB, data=43KB
>
> I/zygote (30902): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
>
> I/flutter (30902): #16
>   _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:700:20)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #17
>   _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
>   (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:275:5)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #18
>   _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
>   (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #19
>   _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
>   (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #20
>   _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
>   (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #24 _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:10)
>
> I/flutter (30902): #25 _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:3)
>
> I/flutter (30902): (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and
>   package dart:async)
>
> I/flutter (30902): ═══════════════════════════════════
>
> I/flutter (30902): Another exception was thrown:
>   'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1153 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
>
> I/flutter (30902): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError:
>   The getter 'debugDoingLayout' was called on null.
>
> I/flutter (30902): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not
>   laid out: _RenderListTile#46ebb relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
>   DETACHED
>
> I/flutter (30902): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not
>   laid out: RenderPadding#0a187 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
>   DETACHED
>
> I/flutter (30902): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not
>   laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#d9f7e relayoutBoundary=up3
>   NEEDS-PAINT DETACHED
>
> I/flutter (30902): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not
>   laid out: RenderPointerListener#e0701 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
>   DETACHED
>
> I/flutter (30902): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not
>   laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#57551 relayoutBoundary=up1
>   NEEDS-PAINT DETACHED
>
> I/flutter (30902): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not
>   laid out: RenderFlex#915e5 NEEDS-PAINT DETACHED
>
> I/flutter (30902): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError:
>   The method '<=' was called on null.
>
> ### Flutter doctor • Flutter version 1.3.8 at /Users/louis/flutter/flutterSDK
>
> • Framework revision e5b1ed7a7f (13 days ago), 2019-03-06 14:23:37
>   -0800
>
> • Engine revision f4951df193
>
> • Dart version 2.2.1 (build 2.2.1-dev.0.0 571ea80e11)

**Update**

According to my test, the error is solved when I use a fixed height Container to wrap the Item. But I want to ask the ListView item is not supported dynamic height widget or any options I should be set. Or it is an issue in debug mode?
Here is the issue solved widget structure:
[Widget Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bf4z.png)

The issue can be solved like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = StoriesProvider.of(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.items,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<int, Future<ItemModel>>> snapshot) {
        return Container(
          height: 80,
          child: buildItem(snapshot),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildItem(AsyncSnapshot<Map<int, Future<ItemModel>>> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
     ...(Create loading widget)
    }
    else {
     ...(Create ListTile widget by FutureBuilder)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not able to recreate this from the code you've got on GitHub. Is it happening every time for you?

Comment: Yes, it is often happening if I build a debug version.
I also make a gif to show the error:
https://media.giphy.com/media/XKGJrdAvgLcy9zyJwM/giphy.gif